# Header arguments in Org mode properties: how to activate them locally?

Tags: org-babel

I do `C-c C-c` on the property ("local set up refrehsed") and `C-u M-x org-babel-tangle` on the code block:

```
* foo

#+PROPERTY: header-args:latex :var val=1 

#+name: foo
#+begin_src latex :noweb yes :tangle ../tex/foo.tex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
x = val
\end{document}
#+end_src
```

I get this as expected.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
x = 1
\end{document}
```

I append to the code block this and redo the same commands:

```
* qux
#+PROPERTY: header-args:latex :var y=1
```

I get this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
x = val
\end{document}
```

In other words, the property of the sibling node has "polluted" the local setup. How can I prevent that?

Man:
https://orgmode.org/manual/Using-Header-Arguments.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Properties specified with a `#+PROPERTY` keyword are global to the file, no matter where they are defined: the last one wins. So when you added a second one for the key `header-args:latex`, it overrode the first one. It does not matter that you did that inside a section `qux` that is different from the section where the code block is located. For exactly this reason, best practice is to have the keywords up at the top of the file: that reduces the temptation to think of them as limited to a particular section[1].

There are two possibilities: you can use keyword properties and *append* the value of the second to the value of the first. You do that by appending a `+` to the name of the property:

```
#+PROPERTY: header-args:latex :var val=1
#+PROPERTY: header-args:latex+ :var y=1
```

That way, every `latex` source block will get *both* variable settings. A useful method to check is to use `org-babel-get-src-block-info` as described in my [answer](https://orgmode.org/manual/Using-Header-Arguments.html) to this [question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/77269/org-babel-latex-picture-resolution-very-low).

Alternatively, you can use a property drawer in a section. That limits the property to that section (and subsections if inheritance is turned on):

```
* foo
:PROPERTIES:
:header-args:latex: :var val=1
:END:

#+begin_src latex :tangle /tmp/foobar.tex
  something
  x = val
  z = y
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
#+begin_export latex
something
x = 1
z = y
#+end_export

* bar
:PROPERTIES:
:header-args:latex: :var y=1
:END:

#+begin_src latex :tangle /tmp/foobar.tex
  something
  x = val
  z = y
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
#+begin_export latex
something
x = val
z = 1
#+end_export
```

Now the identical code blocks in the two sections are evaluated (and tangled) differently because each section has its own property drawer which is private to the section.

BTW, if you find the colons confusing, you are not alone. You might find my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70483855/2561714) to a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70468993/how-can-i-have-global-var-binding-for-org-mode-code-block-header) on SO helpful.

The canonical reference for all of this is [Using header arguments](https://orgmode.org/manual/Using-Header-Arguments.html) in the Org mode manual.

---

[1] Not every keyword works like the `#+PROPERTY` keyword. E.g. `#+TITLE` keywords seem to accumulate: having more that one in the file seems to produce a title that is the concatenation of all the values found in the file (I found this experimentally hence the "seems" qualification - I don't know of an "official" declaration to that effect). There is an old
and deprecated keyword, `#+CATEGORY`, which is specific to a section - that is used in the agenda and that's the only one I know which is section-specific. (BTW, there are also so-called *affiliated keywords* that are different beasts altogether: they are affiliated to a particular element - examples are a figure caption or an attribute of a table.)

Comment: Did you get this working?